# River through hole in Terrain?

Tags: unity-game-engine, rendering, spline

my Question is about Unity with Gaia and Gena (can't keep apart which one the Terrain pack and which the Enviroment pack is :|)

I wanted to create a scenic river flowing out of a mountain, so I decided to create a hole in the terrain and embellish the surroundings with stones. However, I encountered an issue where the rendering of the river stops at the area where the terrain would be. (trasnlated by chatGPT )
[River behind Terrain with Hole](https://i.stack.imgur.com/W2QY5.png)

If you are able to speak German, I would be happy about German explanations.

I also have Asked ChatGPT and it gave me 4 steps.

1. I should make sure that everything is right positioned and that,

- already did.

2. I should check Render distance settings and culling settings,

- well as you can see on the Picture how close the camera was its not a problem about Render Distance and neither the terrain or the River has a culling setting which i could found.

3. I should make my one Shaders,

- is not up for debate.

4. I should use other River tools,

- thought before i Search something else and buy another tools which has other problems i ask the Community

Comment: It might have something to do with the rendering queue of the terrain compared to the river shader. It might also have to do with the way rivers are generated, but figuring out this kind of stuff is hard for closed source assets. Ask the vendor.

Comment: procedural worlds are very helpful especially if you catch one of them doing live streams you can ask they will probably show you how

Comment: So in that picture you want the river to continue forward more?